# Laravel login as another user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am currently developing a laravel app where there are 3 `user_roles`

1. Superadmin
2. Admin
3. Normal

So each role can access the roles below him.

e.g

Superadmins can access admins and normal users account.

How do I allow a authenticated superadmin user to log in as an admin or normal user with a click of a button?

```
USER_ROLES TABLE
id      name
 1      superadmin
 2      admin
 3      normal

----------------------------
USERS TABLE
id      first_name        last_name        user_role_id    password
 1      john              doe              1               *******
 2      jane              doe              2               *******
 3      cassie            snow             3               *******
 4      sansa             stark            3               *******
```

Comment: You can set session variable for Admin and redirect to Admin dashboard on button click.

Comment: Superadmin should have all admin+user privileges by default, no? Can you explain a little bit more. Also there are a lot of packages for Role Based logins.

Comment: @S.I. yeah exactly. It's more clear with superadmin accessing a normal user account. superadmin's dashboard only contains stuff for administrating the whole system. while a user has different features to do. what i'd like to do is a superadmin to access the normal user's account and do the things on his behalf. It's like impersonating the normal user. But all activities will be logged as the actual user(superadmin).

Comment: You can check Entrust or Laratrust or any other package for Laravel Role Based Access. It does exactly that.

Comment: @S.I. i have to create and assign roles and permissions with entrust or laratrust. Is there any quicker way where a superadmin logs in as a normal user and basically does everything a user can on his behalf, but all activities are logged as superadmin??

Comment: Did you check the packages? As I said they do exactly that.

Comment: @S.I. I just went to their documentation for the 2nd time and there is no where mentioning about logging in as another user.

Comment: The idea is that you have Roles&Permission. You're just log in .. as user. Then based on the role of the user which log in you have different permissions.

Comment: This isn't as daunting as it seems. As you have user roles just simply create a middleware to check the user role upon signing in which then you could add something into the menu to display the super admin menu, the admin menu etc. You could also middleware for it to check the userlevel when the person is trying to access a specific link on the menu.

Comment: there's this package called "404labfr/laravel-impersonate" that should help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reading the comments I think you want to do the following:

- Editing anothers profile (or anything else)
- your rights have to be higher than the ones of the other account
- everything should be logged by the user that changed the entries, not by the owner

The following solutions are build in ones, maybe there are some packages for laravel to solve this kind of problem.

[Auth::loginById($otherUserId)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods) could be one solution:

- you have to check if the user is allowed to log in in this profile
- you have to remember your own user id (in a session) to add it for the log
- you can access only the pages the user can see (not the admin pages)

Another approach would be to use [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#writing-policies)

e.g. you are user 1 and want to edit the profile of user 3. in the update function `user/3/profile`. You call a policy function where you check if your user_role_id is smaller than the other ones. Then the record will be saved and the logger will log it away with your user id.

Both ways have pros and cons.
Login with the id will give you exact the view of the other user. But you have to modify your logger (instead of Auth::id() use something with a session). Then you can implement a little button with (jump back to own profile) to login back in your own account.
Using polices will be easier for the logger, but at every part you have to implement the check with the policy.

Not knowing the size and complexity of your project I would suggest the first solution. I implemented it by myself in one project but without the logger function.

Comment: `you have to remember your own user id (in a session) to add it for the log` -- what's the best pattern for this?

Comment: @AliRaza yeah, I added the original user as a session variable, using the `session()` function

Answer (score 24):

You can use the following methods to log in any user

```
$userId = 1;
Auth::loginUsingId($userId, true);
```

or

```
$user = User::find(1);
Auth::login($user);
```

If you have set up roles in your user model you could use something like

```
    //check if the current user is superadmin
    $userRoles = Auth::user()->getRoleNames()->toArray();
        if (in_array('superadmin', $userRoles)) {
             //login the user
             Auth::login($user);          
        }
```

Comment: instead of `$user = User::where('id',1);`, it should be `$user = User::find(1);` or `$user = User::where('id',1)->first();` or else you will get Exception: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`

Answer (score 1):

First you need add 2 columns to user table: type(integer 1=admin, 2=some other) and active (boolean 1 to true and 0 false)

php artisan make:migration add_cols_to_users_table --table=users

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('type')->default(0);
        $table->boolean('active')->default(0);
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
        $table->dropColumn(['type', 'active']);
    });
}
}
```

link on some page

```
 <a href="{{ url('impersonate') }}/{{ $user->id }}" class="btn btn-success">Enter as {{$user->name}}</a>
```

someUserController.php:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class someUserController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $id = Auth::id();
    $user = User::find($id);

    //echo '<pre>ID:'.$id.' - '.print_r($user,1); die();

    if($user->type !== 1)  //1 for type admin
    {
        echo ' error not admin (nice try!).';
        die();
    }
}

public function impersonate($id)
{       
    Auth::logout(); // for end current session
    Auth::loginUsingId($id);

    return redirect()->to('get-dashboard');
}
```

}

routes.php | web.php

```
Route::get('/impersonate/{id}', 'someUserController@impersonate');

Route::get('get-dashboard', function () {

    $id = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::id();
    $user = \App\User::find($id);

    //echo '<pre>'.print_r($user,1); die();

    if(!$user->active) return redirect('404-page');


    switch($user->type)
    {
        case 1: return redirect('x-url-dashboard-1'); break;
        case 2: return redirect('x-url-dashboard-2'); break;
        case 3: return redirect('x-url-dashboard-3'); break;
    }


});
```