# Laravel 9 login as another user

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-fortify

I want to be able to login as another user from my administrator account.

I'm making a SPA application with Inertia Js using laravel fortify to handle sessions and login.

In laravel 8 i was able to login as another user but with the laravel 9 the login method makes me logout.

```
$user = User::find(2);
Auth::guard('web')->login($user); // or // Auth::login($user);
```

I checked about the csrf token , i tried to exclude my uri but nothing changes.

If you have any idea don't hesitate thanks !

Comment: What is the error you are getting? How are you running the code you are showing?(in console or in controller function)

Comment: @Techno , technically i don't have error , i'm just logout. The code is running in a crud controller for test . Initially in laravel 8 i had laravel nova action class which in i was able to login as another user

Comment: Fair enough, how about second question?

Comment: @Techno , i mean i'm totally logout instead to auth as another user . My goal is to be able to login as another user and i don't understand why this is not anymore the case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel login as another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45705087/laravel-login-as-another-user)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes using the login feature programmatically in Laravel requires the session to be flushed before logging in as another user.

```
//IN CASE YOU WANT TO STORE THE ORIGINAL ADMIN USER FOR REVERTING THE SESSION
$adminUserId = auth()->user()->id;

//FLUSH THE SESSION SO THAT THE NEXT TIME LOGIN IS CALLED IT RUNS THROUGH ALL AUTH PROCEDURES
session()->flush();

//GET THE USER MODEL
$user = User::find(2);

//LOGIN AS THE USER
Auth::login($user);

//IN CASE YOU WANT TO STORE THE ORIGINAL ADMIN USER FOR REVERTING THE SESSION
session()->put('admin_user_id', $adminUserId);
```

Comment: I will pray for you  ( ;